# add id to checkbox using loop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, ejs

I'm using node js and express to display a JSON as an HTML table. 
now that the table is showing I'd like to add a checkbox column to keep track of what rows the user has selected. 
so I added a checkbox in the loop that generates the table from the JSON. 
but I can't add an id to each checkbox using my loop variable.

if somebody could help me clear out this issue I'd be really really glad.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/table.css">
 </head>
<body align="left">
 <form action="/results" method="post">
<div class="container">
<table class="table" align="left">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Download </th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>time </th>
        <th>seeds </th>
        <th> size </th>
        <th> provider </th>
        <th> link </th>
      </thead>


  <tbody>
      <% for (var i = 0; i < torrents.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox" id=<%i%> > </td> <!-- the problematic line-->
          <td> <%= torrents[i].title%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].time%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].seeds%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].size%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].provider%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].link%> </td>
   </tr>
<% }%>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</div>


<input type="submit" class="ghost-button" value="Download selected torrents to seedbox">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: `<%i%>` should be `<%=i%>`? You correctly used the `=` in your other PHP output.

Comment: ooooh my bad thought that it was only meant for variables that were passed from the server

Comment: It will be passed by the server because your loop is running at the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used <% 'Scriptlet' tag, this is for control-flow, no output

Should be <%=