# Include table in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

in follow up of my 2 previous questions : 
[get data from async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438910/get-data-from-async-function)
 and 
[add id to checkbox using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459729/add-id-to-checkbox-using-loop/)

I'm now trying to access the checked checkboxes using nodejs and express in the table when i click the button in my results page 
but trying to log req.body only gives me empty string or undefined.

I added a text input just to see if everything was working as intended and yes i could log it's content on the result page when i clicked the button, so the issue definitely comes from the table and the checkboxes.

Here is my code so far:

**Server** :

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const TorrentSearchApi = require('torrent-search-api')
TorrentSearchApi.enableProvider('Yggtorrent','login', 'password')
//TorrentSearchApi.enableProvider('1337x');
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

var torrentsG = []; //empty global variable to store the torrents

const search = async query => {
  const loweredQuery = query.toLowerCase()
  const torrents = await TorrentSearchApi.search(loweredQuery, 'All', 5)
  return JSON.stringify(torrents)
}

app.get('/', (_, res) => res.render('index'))

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
const torrents = await search(req.body.torrent)
torrentsG = JSON.parse(torrents);
//console.log(torrentsG); 
res.redirect('/results');
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})


app.get('/results',(_ ,res) => res.render('results', {torrents:torrentsG}))
app.post('/results',function (req,res){
console.log(req.body);

})
```

**Client**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/table.css">
 </head>
<body align="left">
<div class="container">
 <form action="/results" method="post">

<input name="torrent" type="text" class="ghost-input" placeholder="Search a Torrent" required>

<table name="tableau" class="table" align="left">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Download </th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>time </th>
        <th>seeds </th>
        <th>size </th>
        <th>provider </th>
        <th>link </th>
      </thead>


  <tbody name="TBODY">
      <% for (var i = 0; i < torrents.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" Class="checkbox"> </td> 
          <td> <%= torrents[i].title%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].time%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].seeds%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].size%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].provider%> </td>
          <td> <%= torrents[i].link%> </td>
   </tr>
<% }%>
  </tbody>

</table>
<input type="submit" class="ghost-button" value="Download selected torrents to seedbox">

</form>

</div>
</body>


</html>
```

As you can see i tried giving names to the parents elements of the checkboxes so that they would atleast appear in the req.body() without any success.
On the otherhand, the "torrent" text input is correctly recorded in the req.body

Thanks by advance for your answers and i hope this will be the last one about this "project"

Answer (score 2):

You can isolate a part of your data inside a  , for example in name=“data[nameField]”. And get only this parts with console.log(req.body.data).

Example with handlebars :

```
 <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[{{description}}]" value="{{cost}}">
 </td>
```

Example with handlebars + helpers:

```
 <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[{{removeSpace descrizione}}]" value="{{costo}}">
 </td>  

  //Helpers for removeSpace
  removeSpace:  function(value){  
    result = value.replace(/\s/g,'')
    return result ;
  },
```

Example for multi fields:

```
<tr>
    <td name={{descrizione}}>{{descrizione}}</td>
    <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[{{description}}]" value="{{costo}}">
    </td>  
    <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[{{quantity}}-q]" value="{{quantita}}">
    </td>
    <td name={{um}}>{{um}}</td>          
</tr>
```